# Postgresql: Backup and restore some tables with primary keys

Tags: postgresql

I have a production Postgresql database which consist of 70 tables. Some of them are very big and some are small. And I have my local Postgresql database on my local machine. I want to make some of my local database tables's content be the same as production ones. If I just backup some tables with pgAdmin on production database and then try to restore on my local machine I got constrain errors. Because for example table A has foreign key to table B and so on.

How could I copy some tables from production database and restore normally on my local machine which has already scheme and tables and without constrain errors?

P.s. I couldn't just dump all production database because some of tables are **VERY BIG**.

Answer (score 1):

Dump complete production database, but without data in case of large tables:

```
$ pg_dump -t <VERY_BIG_TABLE_NAME> -s
```

If you want data also, avoid the `-s` option. Since you will have to repeat this 70 times, quicker solution is dividing tables into schemas:

```
$ pg_dump -n <SCHEMA_NAME_WITH_VERY_BIG_TABLES> -s
$ pg_dump -n <SCHEMA_NAME_WITH_SMALL_TABLES>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood, but if you got constraint check errors you can disable the foreign key constraints, restore the tables and enable them again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-create table structure in your local database but add `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` options to problematic foreign key `CONSTRAINT`s
2. Use pg_dump to dump your selected table **data** from production DB to a file and write at the very beginning: `BEGIN;`. At the end of the file append:
   `UPDATE TABLE problem_no_1 SET fkey_column = NULL;` for every FK column that causes problems and of course `COMMIT;` at the end
3. Execute this file on your local DB